# Out of Memory error when sending objects big request using NodeJs server

Tags: node.js, post, memory, mongoose, out-of-memory

I need some help with a NodeJs memory error. I've made a service that receives an Json Object, this object is bigger than 5mb, and save it into a MongoDB collection.

I had to configure the bodyParser.json and the bodyParser.urlencoded limit to: 1024*1024*50. So that I could receive the whole json object.

The problem that I have is that the memory usage of the NodeJs server always increases to the limit of 1.7 GB receiving an 'Out of Memory' error when making several requests in a short period of time, with 3 it's enough. Why the Garbage Collector doesn't free up memory everytime the post action has finished?

The error that I receive is this:

> FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - process out of
>   memory <--- JS stacktrace ---> Cannot get stack trace in GC. FATAL
>   ERROR: Scavenger: semi-space copy  Allocation failed - process out of
>   memory Worker 4436 died with code: 3, and signal: null Starting a new
>   worker Worker 3808 is online FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST
>   Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

The method code that I'm using is the next:

```
avail.post('/newAvail', function (req, res) {
    var newAv = new Availabitiy(req.body);
    newAv .save(function(err, newAv ){
        if(req.accepts('json')){
            if(err){
                return res.status(500).json({
                    message : 'Error saving Item',
                    error: err
                });
            }
            return res.json({
                message: 'saved',
                _id: newAv.id
            });
        }else{
            if(err){
                return res.status(500).send('500: Internal Server Error');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

To comunicate with the mongoDB dataBase I'm using mongoose ODM

Can I some how force NodeJs to clean memory when the post action has finished?

The version of NodeJs that I'm using is: 4.4.5

Comment: _"this object is bigger than 5mb"_. So, how big is it? And what does it contain? I wonder if using Mongoose is a wise idea if you're using these sorts of large documents. Depending on what's actually in them, it may be better to store parts of them in storage that's more appropriate.

Comment: The Json Object size is between 5 and 7 MB, It's a whole Json document that fits the documents to be inserted, it will only be sent on initialization, after that the size of documents will be less than 1mb (updates of the original document)

Comment: You should probably try to pinpoint what's causing the memory issue. For instance, don't `.save()` the document, just instantiate it, to see if that makes a difference. Or perhaps work around using Mongoose and save those large documents to MongoDB directly.